# TortoiseSVN 1.8 : Externals greyed out in commit dialog

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a problem with TortoiseSVN 1.8.1. The problem is similar to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755618/svn-committing-externals-on-commit-of-main-trunk).

In fact, I have a project that contains a folder with multiple externals. When I want to commit changes in more than one external at once or together with changes to my main project, the externals are always greyed out (like in the second picture [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755618/svn-committing-externals-on-commit-of-main-trunk)). I cannot select them and have to commit each external separately.

The problem occurs with any parent folder of the externals. The externals are in the same repository as my main project. The problem first occured with TortoiseSVN 1.8; it worked with TortoiseSVN 1.7.

Is this a bug in TortoiseSVN 1.8? Or is there a property to enable such a commit? Do I have to set up my externals property in a special way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no bug. That's TortoiseSVN correct behavior.

Externals don't accept changes by default. Suppose you are using an external from a repository that you are not a contributor, or that is located outside of your repository. TortoiseSVN can track the file changes, but you can't perform a single commit in two repositories at once.

Even if all paths are in your repository structure, perform single commits in two repositories is a bad practice.

Comment: Sometimes a changelist logically spans multiple externals in more complicated real-world set ups. To break up a LOGICAL change into two or more separate PHYSICAL commits is a worse bad practice, to me, than performing a single commit in 2 externals. Notice the latest command line now provides the --include-externals switch, so this is sanctioned behavior. Tortise should provide an optional override (shift-click or something).

Comment: Good point. Now is wait for the TortoiseSVN team to alter this behavior to reflect the new switch.