# grayed-out checkboxes when committing to multiple svn externals

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-externals

(Similar to [13755618](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755618/svn-committing-externals-on-commit-of-main-trunk))

I am currently working on a project which is composed of multiple software units stored on one SVN repository.  To assemble the project, I am using svn:externals as below (although in reality there is more like 30-40 individual units...)

```
(local)                            (url)
Sources/<layer>/software_unit_1    <svn server>/components/software_unit_1/source_code

Sources/<layer>/software_unit_2    <svn server>/components/software_unit_2/source_code

Sources/<layer>/software_unit_3    <svn server>/components/software_unit_3/source_code
```

Commits often comprise of changes to multiple software units.  However, I an unable to select any files from the externals in the tortoise svn commit dialog:

[image: tortoise svn commit window showing greyed-out checkboxes]

...so how do I commit to externals?  Everything is versioned under the same repository so I don't see a problem why this shouldn't be possible.

Comment: This is how TortoiseSVN works: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18448400/7225096

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TortoiseSVN 1.8 : Externals greyed out in commit dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448400/tortoisesvn-1-8-externals-greyed-out-in-commit-dialog)

Comment: Well, from what I understood, the conclusion from the comments is that it is incorrect behavior.  Anyway, this seems to be possible when changes to be committed are direct children of the external containing folder, so it's inconsistent whatever the intended behaviour...  I say bug.

Comment: Do these externals point to different repositories?

Comment: @bahrep No, different subrepositories of the same repository